# A library I am using is opening an input stream and not closing it. How can I close it?

Tags: java, inputstream

Every few days, I get a SocketException, too many files open. I tracked the issue to a temporary pdf file that is being used during a certain process. The process passes a name of a temporary file that the library creates. At some point, the library opens an input stream but doesn't close it. Given that my code only has the name of the file, is there any way for me to close the stream?

Details:
Java Web App running in Tomcat6

Comment: Can you show how you call the library, it may help us develop ways around the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The best approach is to request a version of this library with this bug fixed.
2. If this is not possible, get the sources, fix the bug yourself.
3. If you can't (only a binary jar file), try a tool like jd-gui, decompile the faulty class, fix, recompile that class and replace the .class in the jar.
4. If it still does not work use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and add a close statement at the right place. THIS SOLUTION SHOULD BE AVOIDED. It's complex if you do not master this technology.

Comment: How about using reflection?

Comment: @ Adriaan Koster: As I understand the issue of the OP, it may be impossible to access the stream from the outside world in time before the reference to the object is lost.

Comment: Probably, yes, but it might be a private field... And in that case I think reflection would be preferable to byte code manipulation.

Comment: I ended up using jd-gui. The source wasn't available. The original developer made some effort so close the stream, but the problem was that an exception was being thrown and the stream ended up left open.